# Filter *controls* with dc.js?

Tags: filter, dc.js

In the dc.js examples I have seen, the user applies a filter to a dimension by selecting values on a chart - and sometimes by selecting a legend item. How does one implement a dedicated *control* for selecting values?

[image]

Comment: It would be great if dc.js were a general system that could be applied to anything, but no... Each chart needs to be implemented, and each control. We have a [combo box](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/cbox-menu.html), a [select menu](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/select.html), a [text filter](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/text-filter-widget.html)... anything else you'd have to implement yourself. It's not that hard, but it's not automatic either.

Answer (score 1):

So if you want a one off custom UI control, you can handle the events and call the relevant filters and redraw (the same way it's done when clicking on existing charts)

If you want to have something re-usable, you need to implement a new "graph" type, check the select menu code, it's not a lot of extra boilerplate

Btw, between combo box and select menu, you should be able to implement everything but the sider